# OpenCv for NifTi files Python

Tags: python, opencv, nifti

I want to use openCV to create a mask for my Nifti pictures. I found how to show one picture with plot but not with openCV. Sadly I still haven't figured how.

[This is the link to the nifti image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hYAU0LqTSnsYjWpBle2ZF3J_XQ-cjbIE/view?usp=sharing)

I tried this:

```
img = nib.load(r'mypicture.nii.gz')
image_data = img.get_fdata()

height, width, depth = image_data.shape
print(height, width, depth)

plt.imshow(image_data[:, :, 50], cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

I obtain this:
[image obtained with matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPchz.png)

But when I tried to do with openCV:

```
cv.imshow('T1', image_data[:, :, 50])
cv.waitKey(0)
```

[This is what I obtain with open CV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHmAR.png)

Also, I wanted to know if it's possible to do a 3D threshold with open CV

Comment: What is different about these images?

Comment: @Royal can you please share the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including a sample Nifti image so we can test your code on your image and understand your problem? otherwise `show` function in  `OpenCV` and `Matplotlib` do the same thing in general!

Comment: Hello I added the nifti image and the pictures I obtain with matplotlib and opencv.